# PIG Error - Not reading from local filesystem

Tags: apache-pig

despite running my pig script using a

pig -x local

I am getting an error as follows

failed to read data from "file:///home/tom/Desktop/mycricket.txt"

Actually my file is present in /home/tom/Desktop. Why is not connecting to local filesystem?

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = load '/home/tom/Desktop/mycricket.txt' Using PigStorage();
Dump A;
```

Comment: Thanks Kishore. Will this work if i do as a script... I'll try anyway.